# Toggle an button based on voice input

Tags: android, android-widget, android-button

I'm trying to create an application in which the button can be toggled based on voice input. However i have never worked on such an requirement.

The application is like: I have a 3 toggle button, one to switch on/off the fan, another to switch on/off a bulb and another whose functionality is yet to be designed.

I kindly request the readers to provide useful suggestions or answers to proceed regarding the same. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have created a UI and have used setonclick listener option right now. Next i want to implement voice input so asking for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [RecognizerIntent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/RecognizerIntent.html) for voice input and use the result for toggling the buttons. [Here](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/android-speech-to-text-api/) is a good tutorial. Also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11789791/android-speech-to-text-example) might helpful to you.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. +1 for your efforts.

Answer (score 1):

You need to write a speech recognizer service, otherwise if the Google recognizer app did not understand or time out error then the user has to press the speak again button to speak. You can get a working code for a speech recognizer service at my answer [Android Speech Recognition as a service on Android 4.1 & 4.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14940657/android-speech-recognition-as-a-service-on-android-4-1-4-2/14950616#14950616)