# unable to get android speech recogniser to start listening

Tags: android, speech-recognition

I have created an android speech recognition service and able to get the service started from an intent, however am unable to get the speech recogniser to start listening to voice commands.

Below is my code:

MainActivity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Intent i= new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyService.class);
    // potentially add data to the intent
    i.putExtra("KEY1", "Value to be used by the service");
    getApplicationContext().startService(i);

}
```

Service Code:

```
public void onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate();
        mAudioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE); 
        mSpeechRecognizer = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(this);
        mSpeechRecognizer.setRecognitionListener(new SpeechRecognitionListener());
        mSpeechRecognizerIntent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
        mSpeechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
                                         RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
        mSpeechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE,
                                         this.getPackageName());

    }


protected class IncomingHandler extends Handler
{
    private WeakReference<MyService> mtarget;

    IncomingHandler(MyService target)
    {
        mtarget = new WeakReference<MyService>(target);
    }


    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg)
    {
        final MyService target = mtarget.get();

        switch (msg.what)
        {
            case MSG_RECOGNIZER_START_LISTENING:

                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
                {
                    // turn off beep sound  
                    if (!mIsStreamSolo)
                    {
                        mAudioManager.setStreamSolo(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL, true);
                        mIsStreamSolo = true;
                    }
                }
                 if (!target.mIsListening)
                 {
                     target.mSpeechRecognizer.startListening(target.mSpeechRecognizerIntent);
                     target.mIsListening = true;
                    //Log.d(TAG, "message start listening"); //$NON-NLS-1$
                 }
                 break;

             case MSG_RECOGNIZER_CANCEL:
                if (mIsStreamSolo)
               {
                    mAudioManager.setStreamSolo(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL, false);
                    mIsStreamSolo = false;
               }
                  target.mSpeechRecognizer.cancel();
                  target.mIsListening = false;
                  //Log.d(TAG, "message canceled recognizer"); //$NON-NLS-1$
                  break;
         }
   } 
} 

// Count down timer for Jelly Bean work around
protected CountDownTimer mNoSpeechCountDown = new CountDownTimer(5000, 5000)
{

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish()
    {
        mIsCountDownOn = false;
        Message message = Message.obtain(null, MSG_RECOGNIZER_CANCEL);
        try
        {
            mServerMessenger.send(message);
            message = Message.obtain(null, MSG_RECOGNIZER_START_LISTENING);
            mServerMessenger.send(message);
        }
        catch (RemoteException e)
        {

        }
    }
};

@Override
public void onDestroy()
{
    super.onDestroy();

    if (mIsCountDownOn)
    {
        mNoSpeechCountDown.cancel();
    }
    if (mSpeechRecognizer != null)
    {
        mSpeechRecognizer.destroy();
    }
}

protected class SpeechRecognitionListener implements RecognitionListener
{

    @Override
    public void onBeginningOfSpeech()
    {
        // speech input will be processed, so there is no need for count down anymore
        if (mIsCountDownOn)
        {
            mIsCountDownOn = false;
            mNoSpeechCountDown.cancel();
        }               
        //Log.d(TAG, "onBeginingOfSpeech"); //$NON-NLS-1$
    }

    @Override
    public void onBufferReceived(byte[] buffer)
    {

    }

    @Override
    public void onEndOfSpeech()
    {
        //Log.d(TAG, "onEndOfSpeech"); //$NON-NLS-1$
     }

    @Override
    public void onError(int error)
    {
        if (mIsCountDownOn)
        {
            mIsCountDownOn = false;
            mNoSpeechCountDown.cancel();
        }
         mIsListening = false;
         Message message = Message.obtain(null, MSG_RECOGNIZER_START_LISTENING);
         try
         {
                mServerMessenger.send(message);
         }
         catch (RemoteException e)
         {

         }
        //Log.d(TAG, "error = " + error); //$NON-NLS-1$
    }

    @Override
    public void onEvent(int eventType, Bundle params)
    {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPartialResults(Bundle partialResults)
    {

    }

    @Override
    public void onReadyForSpeech(Bundle params)
    {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
        {
            mIsCountDownOn = true;
            mNoSpeechCountDown.start();

        }
        //Log.d(TAG, "onReadyForSpeech"); //$NON-NLS-1$
    }

    @Override
    public void onResults(Bundle results)
    {
        //Log.d(TAG, "onResults"); //$NON-NLS-1$

    }

    @Override
    public void onRmsChanged(float rmsdB)
    {

    }


}
```

Can some one point out where am going wrong? Any help will be appreciated :)

Comment: Where are you firing the Intent? This worked for me - [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11789791/android-speech-to-text-example)

Comment: thanks for the reply. Am starting the service through the mainActivity, the service gets started as well however it is not listening to voice commands.