# Using Google's server of words

Tags: android, speech-to-text

Is it possible to use the library of words which what the Google SpeechToText API for android uses as well without actually using the API? To make it more understandable:

1. I have an app where I can record a speech and save it into my device storage through the use of my app's record feature.
2. I then decided to convert that recorded speech by using the convert-speech feature.
3. My recorded speech is going to be sent to Google's server, and the converted speech will be sent back to my app.

Is that possible?

Comment: 1,2,3 is possible, but I don't understand the 1st sentence of the question. `library of words`?

Comment: By that I mean is, for example, I set my Google's STT feature's language  on my android device to Italian language, and the server will send me the converted text of Italian words. I'm sorry if it seems complicated because I don't know how I'm going to explain it more than enough.

Comment: You're trying to record a sentence in English, and want to get back a String containing the translation of the sentence in Italian?

Comment: That is not what I meant. I was just using that as an example of language. To make it right, I'm going to record a speech in Italian language, and the Google's server will send me the converted text of Italian words through my app.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Speech to Text Example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11789791/android-speech-to-text-example)

Comment: @Gavriel, you said that all of has been said above are possible. Would you mind telling or explaining it to me how could I do that?

Comment: Start by reading the duplicate (link above)