# How to open camera using voice search?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am new to Android development. I am trying to build a voice assistant and I want it to open the camera when I say a specific words. I know how to turn speech to text but I am stuck at opening the camera.

```
if (Text.getText().toString().equals("Launch camera")){
  saySomething("Launching camera");
  // How do I make it launch the camera?
}
```

Edit :

So far, my app turns speech to text and then it looks for if it is equal to a command and respond it that way. I have 2 questions about this.

1. Can I use "contains" for a text ?
2. How can I make it respond it first and turning into text later?

Code

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    switch (requestCode) {
        case RESULT_SPEECH: {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
                ArrayList<String> text = data
                        .getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
                Text.setText(text.get(0));
            }
            if (Text.getText().toString().equals("Hello")){
                saySomething("Hello");
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: do you want to open camera using button click or by voice?

Comment: by voice but i have the code to turn it to text  and see if it contains that command but i just couldn' figure out how to make it launch the camera app

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to implement `Speech to Text` `RecognizerIntent` in android , `RecognizerIntent` will give the text version of what user said and later you can use the result text `result.contains("Launch camera")` to verify that result text contains your desired action , it will basically give you a list of possible results and you can go through all to match your `input`

```
@Override
public void onResults(Bundle results) {
    List<String> list=results.getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION);
    for(String s: list)
    {
        if(s.contains("Launch camera"))
        {
         dispatchTakePictureIntent()
         // call the function to take picture 
         break;
        }
    }
}
```

add the below code into your class

```
// constant variable for request code 
static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;

// function to open the camera app using explicit intent 
    private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        }
    }
```

And later you will receive the response in `onActivityResult` from where you can fetch your image from `data intent`

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
     // verify the successful completion of picture taken
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        // get the bundle 
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();

        // imageBitmap will hold the image you are looking for 
        Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");

        // optionally you can display this pic in some ImageView or can delete this line
        mImageView.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
    }
}
```

[**Code implementation**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5913773/speech-to-text-on-android)

[**Android Speech to Text Example**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11789791/android-speech-to-text-example)

[**Taking Photos Simply**](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html)

---

> Can I use "contains" for a text ?

Yes you can use `contains` to match and verify result that you found , a required text input from user. You should use `contains` because `equals` will only work when you found an exact word to word match and there can be some noise which can effect the response text so safer option is to use `contains`

> How can I make it respond it first and turning into text later?

Basically using  `RecognizerIntent` , the input has been already converted into text and you also need the text input to display it later into your `TextView` so simply you can launch camera intent first and display the text after the picture is taken so store the match content into some `String` variable and later use that variable to display it into your `TextView`

```
String inputcommand="";

@Override
public void onResults(Bundle results) {
    List<String> list=results.getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION);
    for(String s: list)
    {
        if(s.contains("Launch camera"))
        {
            // store your match in global variable to use it later
            inputcommand = s;

            dispatchTakePictureIntent()
            // respond it first  
         break;
        }
    }
}
```

After the picture has been successfully capture then you can display the text

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        ...            // same above mentioned code

        // display your input in TextView
        Text.setText(inputcommand );
    }
}
```

Comment: I already have that but i couldn't figure out how to make it open the camera app

Comment: @BurakDemirelli let me update my answer for more clarity but you have to study "Taking Photos Simply" link part i.e. "Get the Thumbnail"

Comment: @BurakDemirelli if this work for you then you can accept the answer to thank me by clicking on the tick icon on left , happy coding and yeah you can ask more  things unless they are too big for comments

Comment: I made my app turn speech into text and then I made it check if it was equal to the voice command i didn't directly make it search if it contains a command and now i am not sure if I can include "contains".If it is hard to explain in comments i can ask it as a question?

Comment: @BurakDemirelli you can add more details about your doubts in your post and give it a tittle as "Edit"

Comment: I know I am asking a lot but i edited this question so i can make it more understandable

Comment: @BurakDemirelli i told you to put the new content in edit section , now it is completely  a new question , so let me edit so that i don't have to remove my complete answer and always do this

Comment: I'm sorry I messed everything.Thank you for fixing the question

Comment: @BurakDemirelli by this `How can I make it respond it first and turning into text later` you mean , you want to take picture first and then you want to display the text in textview ?

Comment: actually not quite I am not sure if I can explain it but I will try.I want it to respond directly fro speech without turning it into speech but I also want to make it display in the textview (I don't want my program to respond according to the text, i want it to respond using the voice )

Comment: @BurakDemirelli eventually the speech input needs to be converted into text and don't forget you also want to display it as text , so what you are saying it is something like voice recolonization , where you match the voices

Comment: Thank you soooo much!You helped me a lot this project would take ages without this help.

Comment: @BurakDemirelli i am glad that i could help , happy coding :)

Comment: Cannot resolve method "contains (java.lang.String)                                         This is the code:                                                                                                    if (Text.contains("Hello")){}

Comment: Try reading my first code example and read this http://googleweblight.com/?lite_url=http://www.javatpoint.com/java-string-contains&ei=tQVU-dQ3&lc=en-IN&s=1&m=131&host=www.google.co.in&ts=1482979208&sig=AF9NedmhymhAbnMjyIPOcCviQqofx5nFVg.

Comment: Hi, it is me again can you have a look at this question :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41415437/how-to-use-another-speech-to-text-engine-than-default-googles-or-samsung-and-e